# Swift 3.0: Timer not work at first time

Tags: swift, timer

I am newbie in iOS/Swift. I tried many Q&As on stackoverflow.com but not found solution yet.

Does anyone explain me why my timer not work at first time(*), but work fine from second times.

(*)first time: run app to my iPhone(5S), after app finish launch, click Home to go to background, after intervalTime, **startSendDataSchedule** is called but not complete and background end. App is stopped here
Afer some seconds, I foreground the app, **startSendDataSchedule** run again and send data to Server with many logs are printed out.

Second times: From(*) Click Home again to go to background, **startSendDataSchedule** continue runing. I disconnect Server to exit startSendDataSchedule. Ater intervalTime, **startSendDataSchedule** is called and do as my expectation. From now, Timer work fine

What are my wrongs? I would appreciated if anyone answer me.

My code (Swift 3, xcode 8.2 iOS 10.2):

```
static func startFetching(inttervalTime : TimeInterval){

    registerBackgroundTask() // register background with UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask

    //inttervalTime = 5 min
    let date = NSDate().addingTimeInterval(inttervalTime)

    print("Background trace1: thread=\(Thread.current)")
    if (Thread.isMainThread == true) {
        print("Background trace: main thread") // Go to Here
    } else {
        print("Background trace: thread=\(Thread.current)")
    }

    guard timerT == nil else { return }

    // Set scheduler
    //DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.timerT = Timer(fireAt: date as Date, interval: inttervalTime, target: self, selector: #selector(startSendDataSchedule), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        //self.timerT = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: inttervalTime, target: self, selector: #selector(startSendDataSchedule), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        //
        RunLoop.main.add(timerT!, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes) // need if you use Timer init, no if use scheduledTimer
    //}

    // Subscribe to UIApplicationDidBecomeActive
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reinstateBackgroundTask), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
}
```